# How do I do an interactive git amend?

Tags: git

How can I undo parts of the last commit, while selecting which parts using an interactive patch mode?
This would come in useful when you've accidentally checked in a few lines too many in your last commit, e.g. debug print statements or whitespace changes that your editor did for you.

The naive approach is

```
git commit --amend --interactive --patch
```

but this does not seem to work. i.e. it just drops you into an editor to do a rewording.

The ugly approach is

```
git show HEAD~1:path/to/some/file > path/to-some/file
git add -up
git commit --amend
```

but this is annoying because it makes you specify the file beforehand, and makes you re-add all patches one by one (rather than allowing you to un-add only bits and pieces)

Comment: I find sometimes a `git show | git apply -R` followed by combinations of `git add --patch` or `git checkout --patch` can help here - not much better than a reset and re-add, but it depends how much unpicking you want to do.

Comment: Note that there is no "interactive amend", and `git commit --amend` is a kind of a lie (a useful one in many cases, but not in this case). What `--amend` really does is make the new commit have the current commit's parent(s) as its own parent(s). That's all it has to do, based on the way Git makes new commits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about

```
git reset -p HEAD~
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

First command will allow you to unstage chunks interactively (select `y` for the parts you want to get **out** of the commit), then the commit amend will write that into the new commit.

Answer (score 1):

`git gui` offers a gui which looks a bit dry (it's stock Tcl/Tk) but it does a pretty good job at allowing you to view and edit what is about to be committed.

For your use case :

- start `git gui` from the command line
- check the "Amend Last Commit" checkbox (to the right, over the bottom text area where you can input the commit message)
- click in files in the left hand "Staged Changes (Will Commit)" panel to view their content
- in the "file content" pane (right hand side), you can right click to unstage individual lines, or complete diff chunks

Answer (score 1):

This is what `git reset` is good for. You can

```
git reset HEAD^
git add --interactive
git commit --amend
```

to "un-stage" the last commit, re-add the parts you want, and then rewrite the commit (leaving the other changes un-staged, for you to work on or discard).

You can also use `git reset -p` to choose hunks to un-stage, in a way that's just like (but opposite) `git add -p`.